# How does Sinatra know which environment to use?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I uploaded a Sinatra app to the server (heroku). But it seems like the app acts itself like it's at a localhost unlike my another Rails app which works well there.

So how do I check if my Sinatra app uses the correct environment or not? And how does Sinatra know which environment to use?

Comment: [In Sinatra's documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) there is `set :environment, :production`.

Comment: I saw it. So how do I use them?

Comment: Put it in your `app.rb` or what is your base file.

Comment: It's already there. Did you try it?

Comment: I mean, it's not there and it should not be there. If I set `set :environment, :production` it would be executed in a production mode always, even at localhost. There should be another way.

Comment: Maybe this will help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832060/sinatra-configuring-environments-on-the-fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832060/sinatra-configuring-environments-on-the-fly)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev, nu chto ti gadaesh? Ya eto toze uze videl. Ti sam-to proboval? Vidimo net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By nature heroku will take care of setting the environment. By default it's "production". In case you have different config/behavior for different use case, you would have to code that first.

For example

```
if ENV=="production"
  # do something
elsif ENV=="staging"
  # do something else
end
```

I am not sure why would you want to set environment explicitly to "production" or something else. That should be left at discretion of hosting environment.

**Update**

More info on [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)

**Further update**

```
 heroku run printenv
```

above should list environment variables.

Comment: How do make sure which one is being used at heroku?

Comment: One crude way is to use irb `heroku run irb` and then `p ENV` you should be able to see something like `"RACK_ENV"=>"production"`

Comment: Updated answer, try `heroku run printenv`

Answer (score 0):

I add an environment variable to all my heroku instances:

```
heroku config:add APP_NAME=<myappname>
```

Then, for Sinatra, I have the following in the config.ru:

```
# detect environments and setup some passwords
case ENV['APP_NAME'] 
  when 'prod-damon'
    # whatever for production
  when 'dev-damon'
    # whatever for development on Heroku
  else
    # whatever for local
end
```